# Array creation - Zygote error

Tags: android, arrays, dynamic, nullpointerexception

I am relatively new to Android and i want to create an array that increases in size and i declared an array like this:

```
private Sprite something[]; //sprite is my custom class that does sprites
```

And i want to add elements like this, but it gives me error...

```
    something[i++] = new Sprite(spriteSheet,numRows,numColumns,true,x,y);
//i is number of elements and Sprite(...) is the constructor
```

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong here, and why i get the zygote error and a null pointer exception?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you know that array has fixed size and can't autosize? And show your stack trace.

Comment: This is not javascript. Arrays have fixed size, as per `something = new Sprite[10];` where the element indices of `something` are `0 to 9`.

Comment: The functionality you want can however be achieved using `List<Sprite> something = new ArrayList<Sprite>()`, and then `something.add(new Sprite(spriteSheet, numRows, numColumns, true, x, y);`.

Comment: No i actually was trying to create a dynamic array one that can increase in size.

Comment: That's called a `List`.

Comment: Thanks! That's what i needed. Can you post an answer so i can award you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't really work like Javascript does. Arrays have fixed size, as per `something = new Sprite[10];` where the element indices of `something` are `0 to 9.`

The functionality you want can however be achieved using `List<Sprite> something = new ArrayList<Sprite>();`, and then `something.add(new Sprite(spriteSheet, numRows, numColumns, true, x, y));`.

EDIT:

Iteration of an ArrayList works like this:

```
List<Sprite> sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
for(Sprite sprite : sprites)
{
    sprite.print();
}
```

However, the following statement:

```
List<Sprite> sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
for(Sprite sprite : sprites)
{
    sprites.remove(sprite);
}
```

Will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

Therefore, you can either use an iterator manually:

```
List<Sprite> sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
Iterator<Sprite> iterator = sprites.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    Sprite sprite = iterator.next();
    ...
    iterator.remove();
}
```

Or, personally when I need to modify the elements on the list during iteration, I use the following:

```
List<Sprite> sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
for(int i = 0; i < sprites.size(); i++)
{
    Sprite sprite = sprites.get(i);
    ...
    sprites.remove(i--);
}
```

Although if I remember correctly, the iterator is the recommended approach.

Comment: Just to ask:
When you remove an object from the array list, how does the iterator react to that? Does it skip, or does it return null for that element?
And what does add do, does it fill the empty spot or does it just add at the end and to override the element you need to do add(index,element) ?

Comment: That was a question that warranted a longer answer, so I appended it in.

Comment: No, i know how to use iterator, that's not what i was asking.

Comment: I was asking when i remove an element let's say 3rd sprite. When iterator.next() is called does it return null because the element at that position was removed, or does it just skip over it?

Comment: Do you mean in a multi-threaded environment? Because that's pretty nasty, that's why I used synchronized and also the last approach whenever I needed to remove something. If you have elements from 0...6; then if you remove the one at index 3, then you'll have the elements from 0...5;.

Comment: The question is WHEN are you trying to remove things. Single-threaded or multi-threaded? if it's a single thread, then either approach works, it won't just leave `null`s lying around in your list. Try testing it.

Comment: I am working on a multi-threaded platform, but the creation of the sprite and it's animation as well as destruction is on one thread so i think it won't be messy. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend the final one for multi-threaded, or at least that's what didn't do random errors of `ConcurrentModificationException` for me.